# How get only the record that was changed/added/deleted on firebase?

Tags: objective-c, ios6, cloud, real-time, firebase

I have this tree:

root/companyId/customers and root/companyId/orders

and below then 3 customers, like

root/companyId/customers/IdCustomer/CustomerData

I attach to all the events:

```
[sharedInstance.root observeEventType:FEventTypeChildChanged withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
    NSLog(@"Data get: %@", snapshot.value);
}];
[sharedInstance.root observeEventType:FEventTypeChildRemoved withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
    NSLog(@"Removed: %@", snapshot.value);
}];
[sharedInstance.root observeEventType:FEventTypeChildAdded withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
    NSLog(@"Added: %@", snapshot.value);
}];
```

at  root/company.

I need to know when a table change, and wich record.

However, `FEventTypeChildChanged` get me the full subtree, even if only 1 customer change. `FEventTypeChildRemoved` only fire if delete customers tree, not when delete a single customer. `FEventTypeChildChanged` fire when deleted, but don't show the deleted record, but the full sub-tree without the deleted record. Also fire when add a new record, but `FEventTypeChildAdded` not fire.

If I only monitor "customers" tree and change a single value, get the whole list of customers in the 
FEventTypeChildChanged. I only want the single record that change.

So, is clear I don't understand how wire this. I want to get notified per-table per-record of the add,change, del events, not get the whole sub-tree and re-process already synced data (similar at how work the firebase dashboard).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The child_* events only apply to immediate children of a node. If you attach a listener at /a, and then /a/b gets added, you'll get a child_added event. However, if /a/b already existed, and you add /a/b/c, you'll only receive a child_changed event, because you're listening only at /a, and the /a/b wasn't added, it was changed.

If you want to know exactly what changed, then you should add additional listeners at the points you care about. At /a and /a/* in this case. Firebase is built to allow the attaching of very large numbers (thousands) of listeners.

Forge works by attaching listeners at every level in the tree. That way we know exactly what changed at each level.

Comment: That means the data I get in the event is not fully downloaded but reconstructed from the changed in the server and a local copy? Like a kind of diff?

Comment: Also, the behaviour of the dashboard is what I like to have. Any hints in how is done? Is using queues? (BTW, I run the queue demo and nothing happend...)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Are you talking about Forge? Which behaviour specifically do you like?

Comment: The Firebase dashboard doesn't use queues or anything. It just loads all the data and renders it using the normal API.

Comment: Ok. I still don't see how know if a child is deleted. The FEventTypeChildRemoved is not called and FEventTypeChildChanged give the full (new list) but to know which child was deleted I need to compare with my local data.

Comment: Ahh... let me update my answer above. You're listeing too shallow in the tree!

Comment: I just updated my answer. Sorry for the confusion! I didn't understand the first time I read it.